# Java SimpleDateFormat format issue with yyyy

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'm having trouble with the `format` method of a SimpleDateFormat object.

The code in question is:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(date);
```

Where "date" is a Date object created using a long int from Calendar.getTimeInMillis();

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Everything is working fine except the year portion of the string.  When I pass the date, the string outputted looks like this:

```
0044-09-10 05:30:24
```

The date object that is passed is created from a long integer returned from:

```
Calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

I believe the number returned from this method counts the milliseconds from Jan. 1st. 1970, which I'm thinking is the problem, but even if I add the number of milliseconds in 1970 years (lol, probably the wrong thing to do, but it was worth a shot :P), it still parses as 0044 in the year portion.

I've done numerous google searches and all seem to point simple issues in the string passed to the SimpleDateFormat constructor, so I'm at a loss here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if any other information is needed and I will do my best to provide it.

Thanks again!

**EDIT:**

I figured I would explain the context a little more:

A technician will run a call, and on arriving to the site, will mark the call as "Started."
The app will then create a `Calendar` instance and save the long int returned from `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()`.

When the technician is finished with the call, he/she will mark the call as "Complete." Again, a `Calendar` instance is created and the long int returned from `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()` is saved.

This allows easy "call duration" calculation.

Now, when the closing form that the technician uses in the app is used, the long ints saved during the calls is passed to a `Date` object, which is then passed to a `SimpleDateFormat.format()` method.

This is where the issue arises. Thanks again, hope this helped.

Comment: if the default start date is from 1970, why your date is set to year 44? How are you setting your date/calendar?

Comment: Looks like 1970 was 44 years ago. You might just add 1970 to the year after passing the `Calendar.getTimeInMilliseconds()` to the date object.

Comment: What happens if you just use new Date()

Comment: Why not just use `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` to get your date (or other Calendar manipulation)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.

@Leo: I'm not sure why the year is set to 44, I believe it is because the integer returned from Calendar.getTimeInMilliseconds returns the number of milliseconds starting from 1970, causing the new Date object to be initialized to the year 44.  (I'm not sure of this though.)

MC Emperor: I tried this: adding (31536 * 1000000) to the long int returned from getTimeInMillis(). It still gives me 0044.

Comment: @MadProgrammer & moo2u2: If I use new Date() it works fine because the time is initialized to now, the date object being passed to the formatter is created from a long int from getTimeInMillis(). I use a long int to save dates and time, because I find it much simpler to compare dates, and calculate time passed.

Let me know if this made any sense

Comment: Date is a container of the number of milliseconds since the unix epoc, which should be the same as the Calendar. There is something different about the getTimeMillus method of Calendar

Comment: @MadProgrammer: That's what I was thinking. So I'm not sure why format is not taking that into account.

Comment: Try using Calendar#getTime, which returns a Date object, try comparing the milliseconds from the returned Date and the Calendar#getTimeMillis method

Comment: @Samurai yes, but I'm exclusively saving the instance into a member variable and just calling getTimeInMillis().

Comment: @MadProgrammer: thanks for the tip, I will try this route and touch base soon.

Comment: If you're using java 8, use the new Time API, otherwise, use JodaTine, they calculate the duration better then subtracting milliseconds from each other

Comment: What is the name of the class returned from Calendar.getInstance()?

Comment: And what does Locale.getDefault() return? (asking for what you see in your debugger if you assign this to a local variable or if you System.out.println(Locale.getDefault())

Comment: @MadProgrammer, It did not work, :-\. Still got 0044.

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine.  What is the current date/time on your system?

Comment: @RussJackson:
Calendar java.util.Calendar.getInstance(): 
Constructs a new instance of the Calendar subclass appropriate for the default Locale and default TimeZone, set to the current date and time.
Locale.getDefault():
Returns the user's preferred locale. This may have been overridden for this process with setDefault. 
Since the user's locale changes dynamically, avoid caching this value. Instead, use this method to look it up for each use.

Comment: and what version of Java are you using?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I am using Java 8, I will look into the Time API, thanks.

Comment: @Drewdiddy611 - I know those things - I'm asking what MadProgrammer sees in his debugger

Comment: sorry, was asking what you see in your debugger

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61016/discussion-between-drewdiddy611-and-russ-jackson).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To calculate duration between date/times, don't rely on subtracting milliseconds, it is highly unreliable.

If you're using Java 8, you should take advantage of the new `java.time` API, for example...

```
LocalDateTime dt1 = LocalDateTime.of(2014, 9, 11, 10, 0);
LocalDateTime dt2 = LocalDateTime.of(2014, 9, 11, 12, 0);

Duration duration = Duration.between(dt1, dt2);
System.out.println(duration.toDays());
System.out.println(duration.toHours());
System.out.println(duration.toMinutes());
System.out.println(duration.getSeconds());
```

Which outputs...

```
0
2
120
7200
```

Take a look at [Period and Duration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html) for more details.

Alternatively, you could use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (which the `java.time` is based off)

Comment: I wasn't clear earlier, this is an android app, and I don't think it will compile using 1.8 compliance.  Right now, this app is set at 1.7

Comment: I'm not sure if I can use the Time API

Comment: Why is using epoc time unreliable?  I only follow this method because my father, a developer informed me that using seconds or milliseconds is reliable

Comment: @Drewdiddy611 Though your said you were using Java 8.  You could use JodaTime instead, which should cover the same basics.  Instead of using `Calendar`, I'd be using `Date` directly anyway ;)

Comment: I started using date, but a lot of the methods used to extract items from the object are deprecated.

Comment: What happens if I start at 11pm and end at 1am?  What happens with Day light savings?  What happens with leap years and seconds?  Calculating duration is not as simple as subtracting to millisecond values from each other...

Comment: The only value you really want is `Date#getTime`, which returns the milliseconds since the epoch...

Comment: +1, you make a good point, none of our techs will ever run at those times, but the daylight savings might cause a problem

Comment: What you consider a "never" condition will be the first thing some one does ;)

Comment: Well, even if they did start at 11pm and end at 1am, the date portion of the finishing time would be the next day, so that would still work right?.. I'm combining the time with a date as well.

Comment: Edit this answer to mention Joda time and I will mark it correct :)

Comment: It's one of those areas, where a dedicated library will save you a lot of time and head scratching ;)

Comment: JodaTime works great, gave me everything I needed, and I didn't even have to scratch my head

Comment: Love JodaTime, more than halved my work load when dealing with some very complex time calculations :D

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque Shame the Time API isn't as function as Joda-Time :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer Goes both ways, Joda-Time has features lacking in java.time, and java.time has features in Joda-Time. Be sure to look at the [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project that extends java.time with additional classes. This project is also a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.

Answer (score 2):

The time that the `Calendar.getTimeinMillis()` returns is the millisecond since the "epoch" time. Consulting the javadoc for `Date` class, you can find that the "epoch" is `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT`. Thus, you code should be fine. I have tested with following code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;


public class Cal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());

        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(date);

        System.out.println(date);
    }

}
```

And it gives a correct output:

```
Thu Sep 11 09:48:30 KST 2014
```

One think I'd like to mention is the 'call duration' is not a date. If you are trying to convert the result of the subtraction between two long value into a Date object, It will fail because the subtraction will eliminate the since-the-epoch part of the time from the long value. The result of the subtraction is just a millisecond.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have solved the issue. It turns out I did not include enough information for everyone to correctly figure out this issue.

In the app, I use two pickers, one for date, and one for time, when saving the date, it saves the date selected, with the time set at 00:00:00 and coverts that to a long int in milliseconds.

using:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(year, month, day);
```

When saving the time it saves the time selected using the same method, but when I was calling `cal.set()` I was setting the year, month, and day, to 0.

i.e.

```
cal.set(0, 0, 0, hour, minute, second);
```

changing this statement to

```
cal.set(1970, 0, 1, hour, minute, second);
```

fixed the issue. My apologies for wasting everyone's time as this was simply a logical mistake on my part..

I sincerely appreciate all the help provided.