# Calculate days between two Dates in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, days, date-difference

I know there are lots of questions on SO about how to get `Date`s in Java, but I want an example using new Java 8 `Date` API. I also know about the JodaTime library, but I want a method without relying on external libraries.

The function needs to be compliant with these restrictions:

1. Prevent errors from date savetime
2. Inputs are two `Date` objects (without time, I know about `LocalDateTime`, but I need to do this with `Date` instances)

Comment: Something like [this for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776787/java-simpledateformat-format-issue-with-yyyy/25777559#25777559)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Not really - Duration is not the best fit to do that...

Comment: @assylias Well, it's better than what the OP had

Comment: @assylias Then what is?

Comment: @MadProgrammer `DAYS.between(localDate1, localDate2)`.

Answer (score 626, accepted):

If you want *logical calendar days*, use [`DAYS.between()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) method from [`java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html):

```
LocalDate dateBefore;
LocalDate dateAfter;
long daysBetween = DAYS.between(dateBefore, dateAfter);
```

If you want *literal 24 hour days*, (a *duration*), you can use the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class instead:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now()
LocalDate yesterday = today.minusDays(1);
// Duration oneDay = Duration.between(today, yesterday); // throws an exception
Duration.between(today.atStartOfDay(), yesterday.atStartOfDay()).toDays() // another option
```

For more information, refer to this document: [Java SE 8 Date and Time](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html).

Comment: That throws an exception, because [the Duration.between method requires temporal objects capable of supporting the SECONDS unit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-).  Instead, try `Duration.between(today.atTime(0, 0), yesterday.atTime(0, 0)).toDays()`.

Comment: Instead of `today.atTime(0, 0)` you can do `today.atStartOfDay()`.

Comment: @REACHUS Maybe the -1 was a bit harsh because the code you propose works, but Duration is meant to measure "time-based amounts of time". There is a built-in way to measure a number of days which does not require converting from date to datetime.

Comment: The better answer for LocalDate's is @Sunil B's answer below: `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(firstDate, secondDate)`

Comment: @Lappro why is it better? It uses the same method as my answer

Comment: @syntagma Ah right your first example is indeed the same, I didn't see that because the `DAYS` came from an import instead of `ChronoUnit.DAYS`. And glancing over details to find a quick solution isn't always the best strategy on my part ;)

Answer (score 197):

Based on VGR's comments here is what you can use:

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(firstDate, secondDate)
```

Comment: This solution should be the accepted answer since it is more concise.

Answer (score 65):

You can use [until](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#until-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-):

```
LocalDate independenceDay = LocalDate.of(2014, Month.JULY, 4);
LocalDate christmas = LocalDate.of(2014, Month.DECEMBER, 25);

System.out.println("Until christmas: " + independenceDay.until(christmas));
System.out.println("Until christmas (with crono): " 
   + independenceDay.until(christmas, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
```

**Output:**

```
Until christmas: P5M21D
Until christmas (with crono): 174
```

As mentioned in a comment, if no unit is specified `until` returns [Period](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html).

Snippet from the documentation:

> A date-based amount of time in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as '2 years, 3 months and 4 days'.
> This class models a quantity or amount of time in terms of years, months, and days. See Duration for the time-based equivalent to this class.

Comment: The gotcha I just encountered with the first version of `until` is that it returns a [Period](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) object.  That'll return a number of years/months/days between the two dates, not the actual number of days.  And getDays() on the Period only returns the days part (not taking into account the number of years or months), rather than the total number of days.  The second version works exactly as desired to get a number of days between two dates.

Comment: Is there's a complete alternative for this for this ? Since it needs Android SDk 26 and above

Answer (score 23):

## DAYS.between

You can use `DAYS.between` from `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`

e.g.

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
...

long totalDaysBetween(LocalDate dateBefore, LocalDate dateAfter) {
    return DAYS.between(dateBefore, dateAfter);
```

Answer (score 19):

> If *startDate* and *endDate* are instance of **java.util.Date**

We can use the ***between( )*** method from ***ChronoUnit***  enum:

```
public long between(Temporal temporal1Inclusive, Temporal temporal2Exclusive) {
    //..
}
```

**ChronoUnit.DAYS** count days which ***completed 24 hours***.

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate.toInstant(), endDate.toInstant());

//OR 

ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(Instant.ofEpochMilli(startDate.getTime()), Instant.ofEpochMilli(endDate.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the DAYS in enum **java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit** . Below is the Sample Code :

**Output :**
*Number of days between the start date : 2015-03-01 and end date : 2016-03-03 is  ==> 368.
**Number of days between the start date : 2016-03-03 and end date : 2015-03-01 is  ==> -368*

```
package com.bitiknow.date;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

/**
 * 
 * @author pradeep
 *
 */
public class LocalDateTimeTry {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Date in String format.
        String dateString = "2015-03-01";

        // Converting date to Java8 Local date
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString);
        LocalDate endtDate = LocalDate.now();
        // Range = End date - Start date
        Long range = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endtDate);
        System.out.println("Number of days between the start date : " + dateString + " and end date : " + endtDate
                + " is  ==> " + range);

        range = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(endtDate, startDate);
        System.out.println("Number of days between the start date : " + endtDate + " and end date : " + dateString
                + " is  ==> " + range);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 11):

Everyone is saying to use ChronoUnit.DAYS.between but that just delegates to another method you could call yourself. So you could also do `firstDate.until(secondDate, ChronoUnit.DAYS)`.

The docs for both actually mention both approaches and say to use whichever one is more readable.

Comment: FWIW... I'm not sure why both exist. Are there times that one is more readable and times that the other is? When/why?

Answer (score 7):

Get number of days before Christmas from current day , try this

```
System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.now(),LocalDate.of(Year.now().getValue(), Month.DECEMBER, 25)));
```

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
public class DemoDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println("Current date: " + today);

        //add 1 month to the current date
        LocalDate date2 = today.plus(1, ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
        System.out.println("Next month: " + date2);

        // Put latest date 1st and old date 2nd in 'between' method to get -ve date difference
        long daysNegative = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date2, today);
        System.out.println("Days : "+daysNegative);

        // Put old date 1st and new date 2nd in 'between' method to get +ve date difference
        long datePositive = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(today, date2);
        System.out.println("Days : "+datePositive);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> get days between two dates date is instance of java.util.Date

```
public static long daysBetweenTwoDates(Date dateFrom, Date dateTo) {
            return DAYS.between(Instant.ofEpochMilli(dateFrom.getTime()), Instant.ofEpochMilli(dateTo.getTime()));
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

If the goal is just to get the difference in days and since the above answers mention about delegate methods would like to point out that once can also simply use -

```
public long daysInBetween(java.time.LocalDate startDate, java.time.LocalDate endDate) {
  // Check for null values here

  return endDate.toEpochDay() - startDate.toEpochDay();
}
```

Comment: In fall in the trap to use ' Period.between(date1, date2).getDays()' without realizing that you loose the months and years of the difference.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is for Java 8, but with Java 9 you could use:

```
public static List<LocalDate> getDatesBetween(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
    return startDate.datesUntil(endDate)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the class or method that best meets your needs:

- the **Duration** class,
- **Period** class,
- or the **ChronoUnit.between** method.

A Duration measures an amount of time using time-based values (seconds, nanoseconds).

A Period uses date-based values (years, months, days).

The ChronoUnit.between method is useful when you want to measure an amount of time in a single unit of time only, such as days or seconds.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

LocalDate dateBefore =  LocalDate.of(2020, 05, 20);
LocalDate dateAfter = LocalDate.now();
    
long daysBetween =  ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dateBefore, dateAfter);
long monthsBetween= ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(dateBefore, dateAfter);
long yearsBetween= ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(dateBefore, dateAfter);
    
System.out.println(daysBetween);
```

Comment: java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit  java 8  implemancation

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.