# Iterate over dates range (the scala way)

Tags: scala, datetime, iteration, nscala-time

Given a start and an end date I would like to iterate on it by day using a foreach, map or similar function. Something like

```
(DateTime.now to DateTime.now + 5.day by 1.day).foreach(println)
```

I am using https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time, but I get returned a joda Interval object if I use the syntax above, which I suspect is also not a range of dates, but a sort of range of milliseconds.

EDIT: The question is obsolete. As advised on the [joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) homepage, if you are using java 8 you should start with or migrate to [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Comment: Just added `nscala-time`'s dependency and written `(DateTime.now to DateTime.now + (5 day) by (1 day)).foreach(println)`. Works like magic

Comment: I get: value by is not a member of org.joda.time.Interval

Comment: That's pretty much my code https://gist.github.com/Odomontois/ea73f9bbfcb4cdc5f1b6

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You may use `plusDays`:

```
val now = DateTime.now
(0 until 5).map(now.plusDays(_)).foreach(println)
```

Given start and end dates:

```
import org.joda.time.Days

val start = DateTime.now.minusDays(5)
val end   = DateTime.now.plusDays(5)    

val daysCount = Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays()
(0 until daysCount).map(start.plusDays(_)).foreach(println)
```

Comment: Note that unless you have other parts of the code base that are forced to use JodaTime, the native java time library is probably what you want. Joda is deprecated. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005861/calculate-days-between-two-dates-in-java-8

Answer (score 26):

For just iterating by day, I do:

```
Iterator.iterate(start) { _ + 1.day }.takeWhile(_.isBefore(end))
```

This has proven to be useful enough that I have a small helper object to provide an implicit and allow for a type transformation:

```
object IntervalIterators {
  implicit class ImplicitIterator(val interval: Interval) extends AnyVal {
    def iterateBy(step: Period): Iterator[DateTime] = Iterator.iterate(interval.start) { _ + step }
        .takeWhile(_.isBefore(interval.end))

    def iterateBy[A](step: Period, transform: DateTime => A): Iterator[A] = iterateBy(step).map(transform)

    def iterateByDay: Iterator[LocalDate] = iterateBy(1.day, { _.toLocalDate })

    def iterateByHour: Iterator[DateTime] = iterateBy(1.hour)
  }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
import IntervalIterators._

(DateTime.now to 5.day.from(DateTime.now)).iterateByDay // Iterator[LocalDate]

(30.minutes.ago to 1.hour.from(DateTime.now)).iterateBy(1.second)  // Iterator[DateTime], broken down by second
```

Comment: Are you using some library? Why do you post an answer without imports? It makes this answer absolutely useless.

Comment: @hey_you What libraries are the used in the question?  What imports are used there?  If you're familiar enough with the context of what the question is asking, what is left ambiguous in the answer?

Answer (score 5):

> **Solution with java.time API using Scala**

Necessary import and initialization

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField.EPOCH_DAY
import java.time.{LocalDate, Period}

val now = LocalDate.now
val daysTill = 5
```

Create List of `LocalDate` for sample duration

```
(0 to daysTill)
  .map(days => now.plusDays(days))
  .foreach(println)
```

Iterate over specific dates between start and end using `toEpochDay` or `getLong(ChronoField.EPOCH_DAY)`

```
//Extract the duration
val endDay = now.plusDays(daysTill)
val startDay = now

val duration = endDay.getLong(EPOCH_DAY) - startDay.getLong(EPOCH_DAY)

/* This code does not give desired results as trudolf pointed
val duration = Period
  .between(now, now.plusDays(daysTill))
  .get(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
*/

//Create list for the duration
(0 to duration)
  .map(days => now.plusDays(days))
  .foreach(println)
```

Comment: this solution only works if the duration is less than a month, because `.get(ChronoUnit.DAYS)` only returns the days part, and not the total number of days! for example, if the duration is `P2M5D` it will return `5`.
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50382051/2341325

Comment: @trudolf: Thanks for pointing out!! I updated answer now and I should works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This answer fixes the issue of mrsrinivas answer, that `.get(ChronoUnits.DAYS)` returns only the days part of the duration, and not the total number of days.

Necessary import and initialization

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit
import java.time.{LocalDate, Period}
```

Note how above answer would lead to wrong result (total number of days is 117)

```
scala> Period.between(start, end)
res6: java.time.Period = P3M26D

scala> Period.between(start, end).get(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
res7: Long = 26
```

Iterate over specific dates between start and end

```
val start = LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 5)
val end   = LocalDate.of(2018, 5, 1)

// Create List of `LocalDate` for the period between start and end date

val dates: IndexedSeq[LocalDate] = (0L to (end.toEpochDay - start.toEpochDay))
  .map(days => start.plusDays(days))

dates.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like that:

```
 object Test extends App {
   private val startDate: DateTime = DateTime.now()
   private val endDate: DateTime = DateTime.now().plusDays(5)
   private val interval: Interval = new Interval(startDate, endDate)
   Stream.from(0,1)
         .takeWhile(index => interval.contains(startDate.plusDays(index)))
         .foreach(index => println(startDate.plusDays(index)))
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the `Scala way` is the `Java way`:

When running `Scala` on `Java 9+`, we can use [`java.time.LocalDate::datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil-java.time.LocalDate-):

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import collection.JavaConverters._

// val start = LocalDate.of(2019, 1, 29)
// val end   = LocalDate.of(2018, 2,  2)
start.datesUntil(end).iterator.asScala
// Iterator[java.time.LocalDate] = <iterator> (2019-01-29, 2019-01-30, 2019-01-31, 2019-02-01)
```

And if the last date is to be included:

```
start.datesUntil(end.plusDays(1)).iterator.asScala
// 2019-01-29, 2019-01-30, 2019-01-31, 2019-02-01, 2019-02-02
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.{Calendar, Date}
import scala.annotation.tailrec

/** Gets date list between two dates
  *
  * @param startDate  Start date
  * @param endDate    End date
  * @return           List of dates from startDate to endDate
  */
def getDateRange(startDate: Date, endDate: Date): List[Date] = {
  @tailrec
  def addDate(acc: List[Date], startDate: Date, endDate: Date): List[Date] = {
    if (startDate.after(endDate)) acc
    else addDate(endDate :: acc, startDate, addDays(endDate, -1))
  }

  addDate(List(), startDate, endDate)
}

/** Adds a date offset to the given date
  *
  * @param date       ==> Date
  * @param amount     ==> Offset (can be negative)
  * @return           ==> New date
  */
def addDays(date: Date, amount: Int): Date = {
  val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
  cal.setTime(date)
  cal.add(Calendar.DATE, amount)
  cal.getTime
}
```

Comment: Please, no, not `java.util.Date` again... We are already in scala. But `java.util.Date` died even in Java years ago, and there is already an accepted answer with `DateTime`.