# Get a Period of Days between two Dates

Tags: java, java-8, period

I use [`java.time.Period#getDays()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html#getDays()) to get the number of days for a given period of `LocalDate`s.

It seems to work for most cases, but for a whole month, I get a period of zero days.

The  following test case fails (`java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<30> but was:<0>`):

```
@Test
public void testOneMonthPeriodDays() {
    Period p = Period.between(LocalDate.of(2017, 06, 01), LocalDate.of(2017, 07, 01));
    assertEquals(30, p.getDays());
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that I see the same result.

Comment: I'll bet p.getMonths() == 1. A `Period` is a count of years, months, and days. Your case would be one month and zero days.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe this is the correct result. If you run the following test you will see that getMonths() returns 1. It seems that getDays is not get the total days but get the remainder days.

```
@Test
public void testOneMonthPeriodDays() {
    Period p = Period.between(LocalDate.of(2017, 06, 01), LocalDate.of(2017, 07, 01));
    assertEquals(0, p.getDays());
    assertEquals(1, p.getMonths());
}
```

To get the total number of days between two dates see this question [Calculate days between two dates in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005861/calculate-days-between-two-dates-in-java-8)

To quote the answer given in that question:

```
LocalDate dateBefore;
LocalDate dateAfter;
long daysBetween = DAYS.between(dateBefore, dateAfter);
```

Note that [`DAYS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#DAYS) is member of [`java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to show the link to that question since it already exists?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the link to the answer.  Agreed.  Yeah I think it looks better with the edit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

JavaDoc for `java.time.Period#getDays()` says:

> returns the amount of days of this period, may be negative

I guess this is missleading and it does not really return the total amount of days.

I use now

```
final long daysElapsed = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.of(2017, 06, 01), LocalDate.of(2017, 07, 01));
```

which works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
long daysDifference = DAYS.between(dayInitial, dayAfter);
```

where:

```
LocalDate dateInitial;   //initial date
LocalDate dateAfter;      //later date
```