# Subtracting two date values and returning the different in number of days

Tags: java, date, period

Bearing the risk of being redundant, I would like to know how one can subtract 2 date values and store the result which should be in number of days into an integer. I am using Java for this exercise.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Comment: Also duplicate of: [Calculate days between two dates in Java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27005861/642706)

Comment: My apologies. @BasilBourque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two `LocalDate`s, you can use:

```
longs days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2);
```

Note that `Period::getDays` does something different: for a period of one year and one day, `Period::getDays` will return 1, not 366!

Comment: Oh! I have not tested for that as my program just takes a difference of a few days. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Use [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [Period](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html):

```
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.of(2017, 05, 01);
LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.of(2017, 05, 18);


System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d1, d2));
```

---

you can get the actual date using

```
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.now()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I would like to know if there is a way of passing the present date into LocalDate.of().

Comment: please see my update!

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ `Period::getDays` doesn't do what you think it does - your answer is incorrect. For example, `Period.between(LocalDate.of(2015, 1, 1), LocalDate.of(2017, 5, 5)).getDays();` returns 4.

Comment: thanks, I edited the answer