# How to calculate difference in days between the one from database and current date using java

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc, java-time

I retrieve the date from database (using mysql)

```
java.sql.Date dbSqlDateLastRecord = result.getDate("date");

java.util.Date LastRecord = new java.util.Date(dbSqlDateLastRecord.getTime());
```

and also get a present date

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
```

However I didn't find how to calculate the difference in days between those two. How it can be done? By 'difference' I mean that if I have the following two: 2018-05-25" and "2018-05-24" I will get 1.

Comment: Please search before asking. Similar questions have been asked and answered many times before. For example [Calculate days between two dates in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005861/calculate-days-between-two-dates-in-java-8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean :

```
java.sql.Date dbSqlDateLastRecord = result.getDate("date");

//Convert java.sql.Date to LocaDate
LocalDate dateDB = dbSqlDateLastRecord.toLocalDate();

LocalDate dateSS = LocalDate.now();
```

Then you can Get difference between them :

```
import java.time.Duration;
...
long days = Duration.between(dateDB.atStartOfDay(), dateSS.atStartOfDay()).toDays();
```

Or :

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
...
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dateDB, dateSS);
```

Comment: Thank you!! To send to database a new date, How to convert java's LocalDate to that of database? something like:"java.sql.Date dateDB = dbSqlDateLastRecord.something(); "

Comment: @student you mean `java.sql.Date dbSqlDateLastRecord = java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());`

Comment: As of JDBC 4.2, no need to ever use `java.sql.Date` at all. Use `java.time.LocalDate` instead.

Comment: yes @BasilBourque I agree Ole V.V. already mention that, I just want to show to OP how to solve his problem

Answer (score 2):

Don’t use `java.sql.Date`. Don’t use `java.util.Date`. Both classes are long outdated. Also don’t use any conversions. Get a `LocalDate` from the database:

```
    LocalDate dateDB = result.getObject("date", LocalDate.class);
```

This requires at least Java 8 and at lease JDBC 4.2. My guess is you’re long there. Then proceed as in [YCF_L’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50540930/5772882), for example:

```
    long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dateDB, dateSS);
```

Also just store a `LocalDate` back into your database, for example

```
    yourPreparedStatement.setObject(4, LocalDate.now(yourZoneId));
```