# How to make a program that reads a date and calculate the number of days left until the end of year?

Tags: date, java.util.scanner, simpledateformat, parseexception

i have a really simple problem, i don't know how to deduct the user's date by 01/01 / (the user year) +1. Im really stuck at this point.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String date;
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Dame una fecha formato dd/mm/yyyy");
    date=teclado.next();
    Date mydate =FinalAnio.ParseFecha(date);    
    System.out.println(mydate);
    
    
}

 public static Date ParseFecha(String fecha)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
        Date fechaDate = null;
        try 
        {
            fechaDate = formato.parse(fecha);
        } 
        catch (ParseException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return fechaDate;
    }
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). They are also much better suited for the job.

Comment: No matter if using the modern `DateTimeFormatter` or the outdated `SimpleDateFormat`, beware of the case of format pattern letters. Lower case `mm` means something else than upper case `MM`, and so forth.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate days between two dates in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005861/calculate-days-between-two-dates-in-java-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

   - For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
   - If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).
2. Do not use `mm` for the month as it is used for the minute. For the month, the correct symbol is `MM`. Check [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to learn more about various symbols used for parsing/formatting string/date-time.
3. Learn about the calculations of the period and duration from **[Period and Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html)** tutorial from Oracle. It would also be worth going through [this Wikipedia page on Durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter date in the format dd/MM/yyyy: ");
        String strDate = scanner.next();
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate userDate = LocalDate.parse(strDate, dtf);

        // The date representing 01/01/(the user year)+1
        LocalDate targetDate = userDate.withDayOfMonth(1).withMonth(1).plusYears(1);

        System.out.println("User's date: " + strDate);
        System.out.println("Target date: " + targetDate.format(dtf));

        Period period = Period.between(userDate, targetDate);
        System.out.printf("Difference: %d days %d months %d years%n", period.getDays(), period.getMonths(),
                period.getYears());

        System.out.println("The difference in terms of days: " + ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(userDate, targetDate));
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter date in the format dd/MM/yyyy: 20/10/2015
User's date: 20/10/2015
Target date: 01/01/2016
Difference: 12 days 2 months 0 years
The difference in terms of days: 73
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatador = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
    String entradaUsuario = "02/12/2020";
    LocalDate fecha = LocalDate.parse(entradaUsuario, formatador);
    LocalDate finDeAño = fecha.with(MonthDay.of(Month.DECEMBER, 31));
    long diasRestantes = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(fecha, finDeAño);
    System.out.println(diasRestantes);
```

Output is:

> 29

In the format pattern string upper case `MM` is for month of year (lower case `mm` would be minute of hour, so not useful here). `uuuu` is for year (`yyyy` would work too).

`fecha.with(MonthDay.of(Month.DECEMBER, 31))` adjusts the date to December 31 *in the same year*.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Dude, thanks a lot, you save me, im tried a thousand differents forms debofre and doesntt work, with this works perfect, many thanks!.