# Date can't be converted to string

Tags: java

Can you help me debug?

Parse won't convert my date to string. Here's my whole code

```
String newDate = "05252021";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date today1 = new Date();
String dateToday = sdf.format(today1);

System.out.println("Date Now : " + dateToday);

int betweenDays = 0;
Date hireDate= sdf.parse(newDate); // error sdf.partse
long  between = today1.getTime() - hireDate.getTime();
betweenDays = (int) (between / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Error encountered

```
Unhandled exception: java.text.ParseException
```

> `java.text.DateFormat public java.util.Date parse(String source) throws java.text.ParseException`
> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date. The method may not use the entire text of the given string.
> See the parse(String, ParsePosition) method for more information on date parsing.
> Params:
> source – A String whose beginning should be parsed.
> Returns:
> A Date parsed from the string.
> Throws:
> java.text.ParseException – if the beginning of the specified string cannot be parsed

Comment: `sdf` has slashes separating months, days and years. `newDate` doesn't.

Comment: Make newDate `05/25/2021`

Comment: i did try that same error

Comment: Please, stop using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, they're obsolete. Use classes from the `java.time` package.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://ideone.com/bE6kOi

Comment: thanks oh did not try this one throws java.lang.Exception now its working thanks for the tips im still not familiar on the whole code thanks alot ^^

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate days between two Dates in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005861/calculate-days-between-two-dates-in-java-8)

Comment: _`Unhandled exception: java.text.ParseException`_ Your IDE is telling you that your code needs to handle `ParseException` that may be thrown by method `parse` in class `java.text.DateFormat` (which is the superclass of `SimpleDateFormat`).

Answer (score 1):

## Formatting pattern must match input

Your formatting pattern `"MM/dd/yyyy"` does not match your input `"05252021"`.

## *java.time*

Also, you are using *terrible* date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. For a date-only value without a time-of-day and without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, use `java.time.LocalDate`.

```
String input = "05252021" ;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMdduuuu" ) ;
LocalDate then = LocalDate.parse( input , formatter ) ;
```

Tip: Educate the publisher of your data about using [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats for communicating date-time values textually.

To represent elapsed time as a number of years-months-days, use `Period`.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ) ;
Period p = Period.between( then , today ) ;
```

Or, if you just want a count of days elapsed:

```
java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( then , today )
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score -1):

In the method where this is defined throw an exception like throws `ParseException`. Also, use format your string like `String newDate = "05/25/2021"`.

You can also use a `try catch` block around the `Date hireDate = sdf.parse(newDate);` to catch any exceptions. Ex given below:

1:  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

```
    String newDate = "05/25/2021";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date today1 = new Date();
    String dateToday = sdf.format(today1);
    System.out.println("Date Now : " + dateToday);

    int betweenDays = 0;
    Date hireDate= sdf.parse(newDate);
    System.out.println("Date Now : " + hireDate);
    long  between = today1.getTime() - hireDate.getTime();
    betweenDays = (int) (between / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to change the input to "05/25/2021"? OP may or may not be able to control input. Should OP change his code to throw a `ParseException`? Why would OP wrap the parsing code with a `try` block? What would he do with the caught exception? Please check [answer].

Comment: Hi Robert, noted . I suggested him to change his input since the SimpleDataFormat he has initialise is in the format MM/DD/YYYY . Will try to improve the details and explanation .