# Difference between two dates in JOOQ

Tags: java, oracle, jooq

I have a table in Oracle which contains the column `DATUM` of type `Date`.
After running "jooq-codegen:generate", a Java class was created where the field `DATUM` got the type `LocalDate`.

Now I would like to have a difference between `01.01.2022` and `DATUM` in JOOQ.
In Oracle, it would simply be

```
TO_DATE('01.01.2022') - DATUM
```

However I can't manage to translate that into JOOQ.

With `minus` it does not accept the data type. The `dateDiff` function does not work neither because DATUM in Java became `LocalDate` and it has to be `Date`. How can I transform the type within the JOOQ-Statement? Or any other solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate days between two Dates in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005861/calculate-days-between-two-dates-in-java-8)

Comment: @astentx That is not a duplicate of this question. jOOQ is a library to generate SQL queries, the question you link is about getting a difference in Java itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the functions your are looking for are on the `DSL` class

```
DSL.localDateDiff(DSL.localDate("01.01.2022"), TABLE.DATUM);
```

Please checkout the API Doc:
https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html

Comment: As I have mentioned TABLE.DATUM is of type LocalDate and DSL.dateDiff expects an object of type Date.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please also check the DSL class it has many helper functions.

Comment: Thanks, localDateDiff was the right thing to do. In my case localDate("01.01.2022") however returned null. I had to solve that differently. However it would still be interesting how to do it with the function, maybe it is possible to specify the format or stomething like that to avoid null?

Comment: @Volokh: Use the ISO 8601 format: `localDate("2022-01-01")`