# Span in days between two dates misunderstanding

Tags: java, date

I have a misundertood managing dates in Java when I want to calculate the span in number of days between two dates.

Say we have two different dates:

- Date 1: *1986-01-24*
- Date 2: *2017-04-20*

**Case 1:** I have this snippet of code using Dates:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date dt1 = format.parse("1986-01-24");
Date dt2 = format.parse("2017-04-20");
int intSpanInDays= (int) ((dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
System.out.println("Days between: " + intSpanInDays);
```

Output 1:

```
Days between: 11408
```

**Case 2:** Snippet of code using Calendar:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

GregorianCalendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
cal1.setTime(format.parse("1986-01-24"));
cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

GregorianCalendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();
cal2.setTime(format.parse("2017-04-20"));
cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
long spanInMillis = cal2.getTimeInMillis() - cal1.getTimeInMillis();

GregorianCalendar cal3 = new GregorianCalendar();
cal3.setTimeInMillis(spanInMillis);
long millisInADay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
System.out.println("Days between: " + (cal3.getTimeInMillis() / millisInADay));
```

Output 2:

```
Days between: 11408
```

**Case 3:** Example using a spreadsheet in Excel:

When I use MS Excel to get this span just introducing the given dates and simply substracting, the output is this:

[image]

***QUESTION***

Why is Java calculation code of date missing one day? What is missing or wrong in either case 1 and 2 that does not match the result in case 3?

Comment: I didn't read all of your code, but I've seen enough to know you are overcomplicating. What about simply using `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate)`?

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776787/java-simpledateformat-format-issue-with-yyyy/25777559#25777559)

Comment: What's up with `cal3`? You created an invalid `Calendar` from a `long` only to extract the original `long` from the invalid `Calendar`, when you should have simply used the original `long` value, except of course that using those `long` values was the wrong thing to do in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spreadsheet is taking Daylight Savings into account, and your calculations are naively truncating, and given that there's one more 23-hour day in the interval than 25-hour days, the 23-hour remainder is truncated, yielding a result one day less than the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation!!! I did not consider DST.
I managed to resolve this issue using the native Java libraries `java.time.Duration` and `java.time.LocalDateTime` in combination for calculating the duration in days between two dates and it worked. 
Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 2):

JDK 8 largely simplifies these calculations with its new date time API. The same can be done accurately and simply using the below code :

```
LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.of(1986, 01, 24);
LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.of(2017, 04, 20);
System.out.println(date1.until(date2, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
```

This automatically takes care of any/all the DST changes, leap years etc. which is mostly missed when trying to do the calculations manually.

Comment: Incorrect point about Daylight Saving Time (DST). The `LocalDate` class has no concept of  time zone and no concept of time-of-day. So DST is irrelevant, not "taken care" of here.

Comment: You may say that avoiding the DST problems altogether is even better than solving them. The code prints the correct result, 11409. One more case where the `java.time` classes beat the old and outdated classes like `SimpleDateFormat` and `GregorianCalendar`.